# Why is my scanf function getting skipped?

Tags: c

The second `scanf` function in my code is getting skipped, I don't know how to fix it.

```
void main(void)
{
    
    int x1, y1;
    int x2, y2;
    int dist_x, dist_y;
    
    float angle, dist;
    float sintheta, costheta; 

    printf("Enter a starting x and y position with a comma separating each number (i.e. 0,0)\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &x1, &y1);

    printf("Enter an ending x and y position with a comma separating each number (i.e. 0,0)\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &x2, &y2);

    dist_x = x2 - x1;
    dist_y = y2 - y1;
    
    dist = sqrt(pow(dist_x, 2) + pow(dist_y, 2));
    sintheta = acos(dist_x / dist);
    costheta = asin(dist_y / dist); 

    
} //end of main
```

I've already tried putting a space in-between the double quote and the %d identifier. Changing `scanf("%d %d", &x2, &y2);` into `scanf(" %d %d", &x2, &y2);` but it seemed to not have an effect. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you for your time.

Comment: Add `,`: `scanf("%d ,%d", &x1, &y1);`

Comment: Your prompt says that there should be comma separating each number. So you have to have a comma in the format string to match that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User input has to get matched with the format string.

Your `scanf` has `"%d %d"` while you are inputting something like `0,0`.

Either change `"%d %d"` into `"%d,%d"` or remove the `,` in the input, then the program will run without problem.

Tested on Visual Studio 2019.

BTW, if `scanf` is used in MSVC, then `/D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` has to been added in the compiler options in order not to get a compilation error. `scanf_s` is recommended in the later days after learning and practising.

Comment: In order to be more flexible one can use the character class feature scanf format provides, e.g. `scanf("%d[ \t\n,]%d", &x1, &y1)`, which allows any mix of any number of whitespace and commas between the numbers.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I tried the scanset feature. `scanf_s("%d%*[ \t\n,]%d", &x1, &y1);` works for me. :)

Comment: ah yes, right, you need to suppress that and prefix it with a percent. Thanks.